# Comparison between dictionary items

Tags: python

the thing is that I have to tell the total of products in the a dictionary that are between a X price and a X price

```
a = {"light saber": 229,
"ninja star": 29.95,
"cloak": 75,
"Baguette": 35,
"Hat": 12,
"Banner": 5.50,
"Broom": 130
}

def PriceInterval(priceA, priceB, D):
    """
    Explore the dictionary and shows products corresponding to interval between the lowest and the highest price
    """
    m = int or float
    M = int or float
    i = (D.values())
    return {key:value for key,value in D.values() if i < (m) and i > (M)}
print((PriceInterval(10, 50, a)))
```

Comment: `m = int or float` makes no sense. What do you mean with it?

Comment: What's your question? What doesn't work out for you as you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to print the items whose price is between `priceA` and `priceB`,

```
a = {
    "light saber": 229,
    "ninja star": 29.95,
    "cloak": 75,
    "Baguette": 35,
    "Hat": 12,
    "Banner": 5.50,
    "Broom": 130,
}


def PriceInterval(priceA, priceB, D):
    """
    Explore the dictionary and shows products corresponding to interval between the lowest and the highest price
    """
    return {
        name: price
        for name, price in D.items()
        if priceA <= price <= priceB
    }


print(PriceInterval(10, 50, a))
```